# swift - How to check CoreData exists

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to check if the item exits in coredata if not add it to coredata. How am I going to implement the check?

```
var authorList = [AuthorList]()
    
let articleEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AuthorList", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!)
let newAuthor = AuthorList(entity: articleEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context!)
     
//if authorID is not in coredata then....
newAuthor.authorName = authorName!
newAuthor.authorImage = authorImage!
newAuthor.newspaperName = newspaperName!
newAuthor.newsPaperImage = newsPaperImage!
newAuthor.authorID = authorID!
```

Answer (score 7):

In case any body looking for swift 3 solution.:

Swift 3

Xcode 8x

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Friends")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friendName == %@", frd.text)
    request.predicate = predicate
    request.fetchLimit = 1

    do{
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext
        let count = try context.count(for: request)
        if(count == 0){
            // no matching object
            print("no present")
        }
        else{
            // at least one matching object exists
            print("one matching item found")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Used NSPredicate to filter articlID in coredata...

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FavArticles")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "articleID == %ld", articleID!)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let fetchResults = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [FavArticles]
if fetchResults!.count > 0 {
  println("already favd")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func checkIfItemExist(id: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Products")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productId == %@", id)
    do {
        let count = try DatabaseHelper.context!.count(for: fetchRequest)
        if count > 0 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return false
    }
}
```