# Can Core Data @fetchreqeust a specific field?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Is there a concise way to only pull back a single field from a @fetchreqeust so I can see if a specific id (UUID) exists the results of the @fetchrequest from Core Data?

I have a request which brings back a list of tokens, each having an id which is a UUID:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.id)])
var tokens: FetchedResults<Token>
```

and I am trying to create a function to see if the token has been downloaded already which should look something like this:

```
func isDownloaded(tokenId: UUID) -> Bool {
    
    return tokens.contains(tokenId)
}
```

Can I change the @fetchrequest to just pull back a list of the Token id's? When I do something like this:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.id)])
var tokens: FetchedResults<Token.ID>
```

I get an error:

> Type 'Token.ID' (aka 'Optional') does not conform to protocol
> 'NSFetchRequestResult'

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109719/swift-how-to-check-coredata-exists) for checking to see if a record exists before inserting it, but that's not what I am looking to do. I need the list of id's I have already downloaded into core data so I don't even allow the user to download the token. So I wanted to check, as I am looping through the list to display, to see if I should enable the download button or not. Doing a fetch each time seems cumbersome.

**UPDATE**

Based on @joshgalv's response and @JoakimDanielson's comments ended with this:

```
func isDownloaded(tokenId: UUID) -> Bool {
    tokens.contains(where: { $0.id == tokenId })
}
```

Comment: You could use NSFetchRequest to get the “count”

Comment: I need a full list of the tokens I have in core data already as I am checking it against a list of search results. I don't want to do a fetch request for each one.

Comment: So, yet again, you have omitted relevant information from the original question. Question reopened.

Comment: Change isDownloaded to `tokens.contains(where: { $0.id == tokenId })`

Comment: That is 10x better, @JoakimDanielson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to combine [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest/init(fetchrequest:animation:)) `@FetchRequest` initializer:

```
init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Result>, animation: Animation? = nil)
```

with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675149/how-to-fetch-only-one-column-data-in-core-data-using-swift-3) stackoverflow post. This would allow you to create a custom `NSFetchRequest` that would only query a single column of your object and allow you to pass that into your `@FetchRequest` instead. I haven't tried this but I think it would work.

With that said I do think it would be easier to just use a regular `@FetchRequest` and get the property via `managedObject.id` in whatever case you want to use it, and I don't think you'd be saving much performance by only querying a single column.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I guess you're saying `isDownloaded` should just use the existing  `tokens` and iterate through it to see if it exists already.

Comment: I can mark this as the answer. Just take a look and see if the isDownloaded function is the mechanism you were recommending.

Comment: @lcj how is this the accepted solution, have you tested if it even works?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, instead of querying for the id and getting an array, I just did a fetchrequest, as joshgalv recommended, and queried it. I answered it because he questioned my approach/premise and recommended a better one. Though not a complete solution (tested and all) I felt he set me on the right track.